# Django: Aggregate per "event__pk"

Tags: python, django

I get these query results

`<QuerySet [{'event__pk': 4, 'pk': 15, 'total_gross': 12340000}, {'event__pk': 4, 'pk': 13, 'total_gross': 123000}, {'event__pk': 5, 'pk': 22, 'total_gross': 1234000}]>`

The problem I'm dealing with is I am trying to aggregate `total_gross` **per event**. However, always when I add `.aggregate(Sum('total_gross'))`, Django is just aggregates everything. Any idea how to fix that?

```
max_total_gross_per_ticket = (
    Ticket.objects.filter(
        event__organizer__in=self.organizers,
        event__status=EventStatus.LIVE,
    ).values('event__pk', 'pk')
    .order_by('event__pk')
    .annotate(
        total_gross=F('quantity') * F('price_gross'),
    )
    # .aggregate(Sum('total_gross'))
)
```

Comment: Does a `Ticket` have a reference to a `Category`?

Comment: Events can have several tickets. (It's live events per people can buy tickets for.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should exclude the `pk` from the values, you should also add a `Sum(..)` function in your annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

max_total_gross_per_ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(
    event__organizer__in=self.organizers,
    event__status=EventStatus.LIVE,
).values('event__pk').annotate(
    total_gross=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price_gross')),
).order_by('event__pk')
```

It makes however more sense here to annotate the `Event` object, like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Event.objects.filter(
    organizer__in=self.organizers,
    status=EventStatus.LIVE
).annotate(
    total_gross=Sum(F('tickets__quantity') * F('tickets__price_gross'))
)
```

then the `Event`s will have an extra attribute `total_gross` that contains the sum of the tickets (their `quantity` times their `price_gross`).

Comment: Oh wow, moving Sum where you placed it in 1) actually solved it. Amazing.

Regarding 2) That didn't work. I think the reason is I have more than one ticket per event. Is there a solution for that? Otherwise I will take 1)

Comment: @JoeyCoder: I made a typo in the second, it is `price_gross` not `prices_gross`. The above should work since it will take all related `Ticket`s into account in the `Sum(..)`.

Comment: I still get `Cannot resolve keyword 'ticket' into field.`. Now I tried to change `ticket` to `tickets` in 2). Then I got back `<EventQuerySet [Event: Now Look Attorney, Event: Revenue Test, Event: Revenue Test 2]>`. However, it just seems to ignore the `total_gross`.

Comment: @JoeyCoder: did you specify a `related_name` for the `ForeignKey` from `Ticket` to `Event`?

Comment: Yes, related name is `tickets`

Comment: @JoeyCoder: then it is `F('tickets__...)` instead of `F(ticket__...)`.

Comment: Ah yes that's what I meant. I changed that already but then I just get `<EventQuerySet [Event: Now Look Attorney, Event: Revenue Test, Event: Revenue Test 2]>`. However, when I use 1) I get the desired result `<QuerySet [{'event__pk': 4, 'total_gross': 12463000}, {'event__pk': 5, 'total_gross': 1512900}]>`

Comment: @JoeyCoder: yes the queryset contains `Event`s, but these `Event`s have an *extra* attribute `total_gross` that you can access, so then you both have the `Event` object, and the total gross for that event.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I didn't realize that. Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Just that you made it in four lines while I needed 30 :D

Thank you!